# tengo una duda, es porque no se por que el servidor y cliente no se conectan

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

```
"Código Servidor"
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time


def Enviar_mensaje():
    print("Has selecionado la opción 1")
    Mensaje = input("Escribe algo:  ")
    print(Mensaje)
    primer_socket.send(Mensaje)

def Ver_mensaje():
    print("Has selecionado opción 2")
    Mensajes = []
    try:
        Mensajes = Mensajes + primer_socket.recv(1024)
        if Mensajes != []:
            print("Bandeja", "\n", Mensajes)
        else:
            print("Bandeja", "\n", "No tiene Mensajes.")
    except:
        print("¡Ups!, Ocurrio un error, no hay ningun cliente conectado.")

def MessageChat():
    mi_socket= socket.socket()
    mi_socket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
    mi_socket.listen(5)
    while True:
        conexion, addr = mi_socket.accept()
        print("Estableciendo conexión")

        print("Bienvenido al Chat", "\n", "¿Cuál opción desea realizar?", "\n", "Opción 1 = Enviar mensaje", "\n", "Opción 2 = Ver Mensaje")
        Opcion = input("¡Ingrese su opción aquí!  ")
        if Opcion == "1": 
            return Enviar_mensaje()
        if Opcion == "2":
           return Ver_mensaje()

"Codigo cliente"
import socket
import threading
import sys
import pickle

def Ver_mensajes():
        try:
            datos = []
            datos = datos + mi_socket.recv(1024)
            if datos != []:
                print("Bandeja", "\n", datos)
            else:
                print("Bandeja", "\n", "No tiene ningún mensaje :'( ")
        except:
            print("Ups!, ha ocurrido en un error")

def Enviar_mensaje():
    print("Has selecionado la opción 1")
    Mensaje = input("Escribe algo:  ")
    print(Mensaje)
    mi_socket.send(Mensaje)

def ClienteChat():
    mi_socket = socket.socket()
    mi_socket.connect(('localhost', 8000))#Procedemos a conectar el socket con nuestro servidor.
    print("Bienvenido al Chat", "\n", "¿Cuál opción desea realizar?", "\n", "Opción 1 = Enviar mensaje", "\n", "Opción 2 = Ver Mensaje")
    Opcion = input("¡Ingrese su opción aquí!  ")
    if Opcion == "1": 
        return Enviar_mensaje()
    if Opcion == "2":
        return Ver_mensajes()
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta? puedes ser mas claro?

Comment: Algo falta en ese código. Sólo contiene definiciones de funciones pero ¿quién las invoca? La variable `mi_socket` ¿se supone que es global? No debería serlo, sino que deberías pasarla como parámetro a las funciones que la necesiten. Lo mismo con la variable `conexion` en que tienes el socket una vez aceptado el cliente. Por otro lado la variable `primer_socket` que usas en el servidor no está definida. Debería ser el socket `conexion`, que deberían recibir como parámetro.

Comment: No te entiendo, puedes explicarme para intentar corregir el error. @abulafia

Comment: También hay otro error, dice que el equipo de destino denegó dicha conexión.